# Adding help_text in a superclass attribute

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a model called `MySuper`:

```
class MySuper(models.Model):
    some_attr = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

And I have two subclasses that inherit from this model, called `MySub1` and `MySub2`.

I need to add a `help_text` to `some_attr`, but must be different in each subclass. Is there any way to do this?

```
class MySub1(MySuper):
    # ...
    # add help_text='Help text of some_attr inside MySub1'

class MySub2(MySuper):
    # ...
    # add help_text='Help text of some_attr inside MySub2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve this without having to fully redefine the field would be:

```
class MySub1(MySuper):
    pass

MySub1._meta.get_field('some_attr').help_text = 'sub1 help text'


class MySub2(MySuper):
    pass

MySub2._meta.get_field('some_attr').help_text = 'sub2 help text'
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this for two identical models that have different image sizes. There's probably some brilliant way to generalise this, but for two items my answer will do fine. First create a file called forms.py in your app.

```
from django import forms
from .models import FeaturedProduct, ShopProduct

class FeaturedProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FeaturedProduct
    ihelp = "Image should be 500x220."
    src = forms.ImageField(help_text=ihelp,required=False)

class ShopProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FeaturedProduct
    ihelp = "Image should be 100x100."
    src = forms.ImageField(help_text=ihelp,required=False)
```

Note that `required` defaults to true, even if you have `null=True, blank=True` on your models. Then in admin.py define your `ModelAdmin`s as follows:

```
from .forms import FeaturedProductForm, ShopProductForm

class ShopProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = ShopProductForm

class FeaturedProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = FeaturedProductForm
```

I left out a few imports and the whole `admin.site.register` nonsense. Let me know if you need any more info. The complete list of `forms.FIELDS` can be found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/